# How to get text of each lines in editText in android?

Tags: java, android

I try to render text to my canvas like in EditText render .

I found that sum of width of text in each line(display in EditText) may be greater or smaller than line width (getLineWidth) . I don't know why ?

=> I can't break line exactly like in EditText (100%) . How can i do that ?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

try `fill_parent` or `wrap_content` as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string value of each line. Then calculate the width.

```
String[] multiLines = stringFromEditText.split("\n");

// Get each line
String line0 = multiLines[0];
String line1 = multiLines[1];
String line2 = multiLines[2];

// Then get length of each line by str.length() or sth like that
```